# random forest with NaN values

Tags: r, matlab, cart, random-forest

How can I run a random forest in R using the randomForest library if I have NaN values in the column for some of the predictor variables.

```
rf <- randomForest(class ~ maxf + minf + d + startf + endf + f1.4 + f1.2 + f3.4 + minslope + maxslope+ bslope + eslope + avgsl + noex + noip, data=whistles_nov, importance=TRUE)
```

Gives this error:

```
Error in na.fail.default(list(class = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,  : 
missing values in object
```

Does the TreeBagger function in matlab work irrespective of NaN values?

Comment: use rfImpute to impute the mssing values first

Comment: I would use an appropriate imputation method (or remove the rows with NaN values if that is acceptable) to run it. If it is a class variable, you can probably just add a new "missing" category. If you have a lot of missing values in multiple numeric columns, it could get complicated because of how random forests work.

Answer (score 0):

you should 'read the free manual'  ([link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf))  The same material shown on page 17, under the keyword "randomForest" should also be available in r/rstudio when you type "?randomForest".

[image]

Notice that it says "na.action".  A setting there should drive it to handle "NA" values in a more desired manner.  The default value, also highlighted, says "na.fail".

one of the examples given on page 21 uses "na.omit".  I suspect this omits rows with na values.

You might also consider using missing value imputation to replace it with non-NA values, but you will have to determine whether that is the right thing to do.  ([link](http://datascienceplus.com/imputing-missing-data-with-r-mice-package/))

From this ([link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ensemble-methods.html)) it appears that MatLab defaults to some effective variation on "na.omit".